# Revert to old kernel

Tags: kernel

just upgraded to the new kernel version and now my nvidia drivers does not work properly. Is there an easy way to revert the kernel update to the old one or is a fresh installation the easier way?

Comment: What do you mean "upgraded to the new kernel version"?  How did you update the kernel?  What Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'am using 16.04 and accidentally upgraded the system bias the GUI. I think the installation of Ubuntu base category, where the kernel headers, etc. are updated.

Comment: Is this a common problem?